# Select only rows with COLUMN=<value> if matches exist, or COLUMN IS NULL otherwise

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Here's a sample script to demonstrate the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  city VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO person(id, name, city) VALUES(1, 'John', 'New York');
INSERT INTO person(id, name, city) VALUES(2, 'Mike', 'Boston');
INSERT INTO person(id, name, city) VALUES(3, 'Ralph', NULL);
```

For `city='Boston'` I want *only* the 2nd row to be returned. For `city='Chicago'` I want the 3rd row to be returned.

Comment: I think before providing this answer it is essential to understand the business logic behind what OP is trying to implement. 
jFrenetic, when city='Chicago' do you want all rows which have a NULL value for city to be returned?

Comment: @SeanCox Correct. The example provided is a bit contrived. But the idea is that the **NULL** rows contain the default values.

Comment: If i'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly, would it make more sense to modify your database schema so that the column value defaults to Chicago instead of NULL? This would save some confusion in the querying of the table.
If not, the queries below in the answer work perfectly.

Comment: @SeanCox Sometimes it's best only assume the original poster has a valid reason to whatever we may think crazy. Usually question is simplified to make our "job" easier.

Comment: @SeanCox It doesn't have to be Chicago, though. NULL is kind of a 'catch-all' row. You can specify any city, and if there is no exact match, 'NULL' row should be returned.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for one row:

```
select p.*
from person p
where city is null or city = 'Boston'
order by (city = 'value') desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you can have multiple matches, then I would suggest:

```
select p.*
from person p
where p.city = 'Boston'
union all
select p.*
from person p
where p.city is null and
      not exists (select 1 from person p2 where p2.city = 'Boston');
```

Or, using window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, count(*) filter (where p.city = 'Boston') as cnt
      from person p
     ) p
where (cnt > 0 and p.city = 'Boston') or
      (cnt = 0 and p.city is null);
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using `UNION` vs just an extra condition as suggested by @Zaynul in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56941416/875485)?

Comment: @jFrenetic: I wouldn't be surprised if the UNION solution was actually more efficient with a large table, especially if there could be a lot of matches for the input value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see. In my case, the table should be fairly small (probably up to 50 rows)

Comment: @jFrenetic . . . I offered three different solutions.  One has conditions only in the `where`, one uses `union all`, and the third uses window functions.  How many solutions do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your solution using `WHERE` returns only 1 row. But the UNION query is essentially equivalent to what @Zaynul suggested in the other answer. In his case he used both conditions in the `WHERE` clause. I was simply asking why there is a need for `UNION`, when both conditions could be specified in one `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @jFrenetic . . . In some databases, the `union all` will probably optimize better.  The two methods, though, are pretty similar.

Answer (score 1):

try like below by using subquery

```
select * from person
where 
   city='chicago' or 
  ( city is null and 
    1!=( select count(*) from person where city='chicago'  )
  )
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=83896075794fb4fb45924374e2e35e2d)

```
ID  NAME    CITY
3   Ralph   


select * from person
where 
   city='Boston' or 
  ( city is null and 
    1!=( select count(*) from person where city='Boston'  )
  )
```

result using boston

```
    ID  NAME    CITY
    2   Mike    Boston
```

[Demo using boston](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=59d609bee9dddf583f14727de86c386d)

Comment: I like this solution, aside from the `select count` part which I'd replace with `not exists`. But better than the one with the UNION, thanks.

Comment: @jFrenetic you can appreciate your like by accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple override columns then no good SQL solution will work. Under the assumption that you have only one column - like in the proposed example column `city` only - then you can try either of these queries:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(person.id, person_override.id) AS id,
    IFNULL(person.name, person_override.name) AS name,
    IFNULL(person.city, person_override.city) AS city
FROM person AS person_override
LEFT JOIN person ON person.city = :city
WHERE person_override.city IS NULL;
```

Output for *Boston* is:
| id | name |  city  |
|----|------|--------|
| 3  | Mike | Boston |

Output for *Chicago* is:
| id | name  |  city  |
|----|-------|--------|
| 3  | Ralph |  |

**Note** that you won't be able to process multiple entries at the same time but it should satisfy the illustrated example.